# Capybara Cucumber Find Field

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm using Capybara with Cucumber.

The webpage I'm testing contains many email fields throughout but the ID's and labels for the input field change depending on which page you're on.

What I'm trying to do is create an generic reference to any email field so that one fill in method will work for all pages.

When inspecting the input fields, I can see they are of `type='email`

The full html:

```
<input id="privatekeeper_email_email" name="privatekeeper_email.email" value="" data-validity-message="Must be a valid email address" no_optional_label="true" type="email" autocomplete="off" maxlength="254">
```

In my block below you should be able to grasp what I'm tring to do:

```
email_fields = all('input[type="email"]')
fill_in(email_fields[0], with: text)
fill_in(email_fields[1], with: text)
end
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/input">
```

Reading the Capybara docs, I can see that `fill_in` responds to ID, name or Label so my reference might not work. Is there anyway I could get this block to work?

Like I said, the Id's and labels are not consistent throughout the user journey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already found the element you need to call `#set` on it instead of using `fill_in`

```
email_fields[0].set(text)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I looked at the Docs and couldn't see this solution at first.